# Como saber se um valor é iterável em Python?

Tags: python, iterator

Como posso fazer para verificar em Python se um determinado valor é iterável?

O que determina que uma determinado `type` pode ser iterável?

Por exemplo, como descobrir isso no caso abaixo?

```
a = 1 
b = 'Uma string'
c = [1, 2, 3]
d = xrange(1, 10)
e = range(1, 10)
f = {"a" : 1}
g = True
```

Comment: Quem negativou, poderia dar um feedback para sabermos o que pode ser melhorando na qualidade da pergunta?

Comment: Como @jbueno mostrou o melhor é com o iter. Segue um artigo interessante sobre iterables:
[The Iterator Protocol: How for Loops Work in Python](http://treyhunner.com/2016/12/python-iterator-protocol-how-for-loops-work/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ainda não vi nenhum artigo ou documento citando exatamente como fazer isso de forma "ótima". Enquanto isso, o [miku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89391/miku), do [StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable), citou alguns exemplos.

Você pode tentar algo como:

1- Assumindo que o objeto é sempre iterável e, então, capturando o erro se não for, no estilo *Pythonico* - **EAFP** (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission) - "melhor pedir perdão do que permissão"

```
try:
    _ = (e for e in my_object)
except TypeError:
    print my_object, 'is not iterable'
```

Ou:

2- Utilizando o módulo `collections`

```
import collections

if isinstance(e, collections.Iterable):
    # e is iterable
```

Answer (score 5):

Duas formas Pythonicas de conferir isto.

#### Com `try-except`

```
try:
    iterator = iter(var)
except TypeError:
    # não iterável
else:
    # iterável
```

#### Verificando pela classe abstrata

Só funciona com classes [*new style*](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) - que não existem em versões menores que a 2.2.

```
import collections

if isinstance(var, collections.Iterable):
    # iterável
else:
    # não iterável
```

Comment: Correção - as classes newstyle **existem** sim desde o Python 2.2 e é o que você tem quando herda sua classe de `object`. Na prática qualque rporgrama depois de 2005 que não usa classes new style está errado.